# Error deploying to Heroku using Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, mongoid

I am getting an error on a view when I move my app to Heroku that I am not getting in development or locally in production mode.
I started with the Devise Mongoid app from railsapp.github.com and added bootstrap.

When I deploy to Heroku I get the following error on the Devise navigation parcial,

```
ActionView::Template::Error (can't convert Array into String):
```

Im using Mongoid 3.0.0.rc

I think it's related to Mongoid because I was able to get it work originally with 2.4.10 but now I get other errors with that version.
Also, If I comment out the lines in the parcial where it errors, it loads the root okay but eventually crashes out if I navigate around.

I'm running out of ideas!

I can post logs or configuration files if that would help.

Comment: The shared links partial? Are you using the devise view outise its. Ontroller like in a modal or somethin?

Comment: No, it's rendered in application.html.haml (did I mention that I am using haml?)  It came with the Devise Mongo starter app which I converted to haml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its known and being worked on.
https://github.com/mongoid/moped/issues/21

Advice downgrading back to what you were using for. 3.0.0.rc is also giving me some heroku issues

Comment: Thank you, I dont know how I missed that!  It's interesting that I only get this error on Heroku.

Comment: 3.0.0.rc changed things, with MongoHQ probably also which i'm about to tackle with this push. I had to regenerate a mongoid.yml and remove stuff from my user models to place nicely with devise

Comment: I guess that why it is still ".rc"!  I'm using MongoHQ as well, that all is working nicely locally with the 3.0 mongoid.yml syntax.